# How to get max key that contains partial value in dictionary in unity

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

This is for Unity (C#)

I have a this Dictionary :

```
public Dictionary<int, string> lvl_dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            //Dict tuplas index (Unity), moduleStepCode (API)
            {1,"R1_G1_A1_M1_A"},
            {2,"R1_G1_A1_M1_P"},
            {3,"R1_G1_A1_M1_E"},
            {4,"R1_G1_A1_M2_A"},
            {5,"R1_G1_A1_M2_P"},
            {6,"R1_G1_A1_M2_E"},
            {7,"R1_G1_A1_M3_A"},
            {8,"R1_G1_A1_M3_P"},
```

I need to retrieve the maximum Key given a partial Value.

Example, If I input "R1_G1_A1_M2", I need to retrieve Key = 6.

I've seen answers that retrieve the Max key given a Value, but not a partial value, which should create a subset of the dictionary, and then retrieve the max key, I guess? But I don't know how to do that.

I tried using LINQ

```
var maxkey = lvl_dict.Where(item => item.Value.Contains("R1_G1_A1_M2").max() );   
Debug.Log("max key is : " + maxkey);
```

But clearly i don't know what i am doing.

Comment: Does the code you presented work? Of not, how does it fail? Have you tried any debugging? For example , if you remove the `.max()`, what do you see? What is `.max()` supposed to do?

Comment: This is not the optimal data structure for kind of operation with but it would be something like: `var maxkey = lvl_dict.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains("R1_G1_A1_M2")).Select(kvp => kvp.Key).Max();`

Comment: What does this have to do with unity?

Answer (score 1):

There is two way to get max of keys:

**1- using Max function**

```cs
var max = lvl_dict.Where(x => x.Value.Contains("G1_A1_M2")).Select(x => x.Key).Max();
```

**2- using MaxBy function**

```cs
var max = lvl_dict.Where(x => x.Value.Contains("G1_A1_M2")).MaxBy(x => x.Key).Key;
```